# Database supporting fast approximate nearest neighbor queries

Tags: database, algorithm, nearest-neighbor

Is there a database that supports fast approximate nearest neighbor queries in high-dimensional vector spaces?

I'm looking for a database that would fit the following use case:

- Works for millions of points
- Works for hundreds-thousands of dimensions
- Potentially uses cover trees or locality sensitive hashing for indexing

Does a robust implementation of this exist?

Comment: I know this over 6 years old, but thought this might be useful for anyone arriving recently: https://github.com/netrasys/pgANN/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Although an old post, Weaviate solves this problem, you can learn more about it in the docs or on Github: https://www.semi.technology/developers/weaviate/current/

Comment: I'm not sure why this question has been closed. Meanwhile, Elasticsearch supports vectro-based search through the Dense vector field type: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/dense-vector.html. See also this: https://www.elastic.co/blog/text-similarity-search-with-vectors-in-elasticsearch, and this: https://elastiknn.com/.

Answer (score 3):

There's the [ANN](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~mount/ANN) library which works pretty well for high-dimensional large datasets, but it's not a full "database" and is not a distributed solution.

There's a startup called SpaceCurve (no relation to me) working on a commercial spatial database, so depending on your needs and budget they might be worth looking into.

As a piece of advice: you should think deeply about what "nearest neighbor" really means when you're talking about "hundreds-thousands of dimensions". If you take a million random points in a 20-dimensional cube, the average distance between any two nearest neighbors is already about half the length of an edge of the cube.

This only gets worse exponentially as you add dimensions. Once you're talking about hundreds dimensions you really need impossibly large amounts of points (like > 10<sup>30</sup>) if they're somewhat uniformly distributed; and if they're differently distributed you're better off with other classification approaches.

Comment: why "the average distance between any two nearest neighbors is already about half the length of an edge of the cube"? @smocking

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [AnnDB](https://anndb.com/).

It's a distributed approximate nearest neighbors database that allows you to horizontally scale to millions of high-dimensional vectors.

*Disclaimer: I'm the author of AnnDB.*

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at Facebook's Faiss.

From the documentation:

> Faiss is a library for efficient similarity search and clustering of
>   dense vectors. It contains algorithms that search in sets of vectors
>   of any size, up to ones that possibly do not fit in RAM

Notice, it is only applicable for L2 (Euclidean) distances, and dot products.

Link to the project - [Faiss](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss)